# How to set the focus on a comment in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007, is there a way to "focus" on a comment?  In an IDE, you would do this by pressing F2 for those familiar.

One example of the issue is with Freeze Panes.  Say for example:

- I have frozen the top row
- That row has a comment in one of its cells
- I scroll down a ways so that there is a break in the row numbering
- I hover over the header cell: the comment appears but only the top half of it!  If I try to mouse over it to see the rest, it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enough playing around and I figured out most of it.  Right click on the cell and choose "Show/hide comments."  That will force it to stay even when the mouse is not over it.  It still gets cut off if it is on a frozen pane, but it is at least readable.